# Drupal: Notify admin when comments posted on blog

Tags: drupal, comments, administration, notification, drupal-6

I couldn't find a thread already clearly addressing this. I have a small personal website, basically a blogfolio. I'd like to allow anonymous commenting so ppl can provide feedback as I don't expect them to be bothered registering on my site. However, as the site admin I'd like to receive a notification whenever a comment is posted so I weed out abuse/ spam. I don't expect a large enough volume in the near future for this to be overwhelming.

Is there a very simple way to do this? I'm aware of a few modules that offer similar functionality, just not sure which to use or if I even need a module to do this. Bonus if it's a method that can be extended to perform some automated spam filtering in the future if the workload becomes overwhelming.

I am using Drupal 6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with triggers and actions. Here's a [v6-based tutorial](http://www.scribbledesigns.co.uk/2008/04/03/howto-configuring-triggers-and-actions-in-drupal-6/) (You didn't say which you were using.) that should probably also work for 7 though things might've moved slightly, eg. triggers are now under Structure.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I want. I've set things up as shown in that tutorial. However, I am not receiving any emails from my Drupal install at the moment, including trigger emails and contact form emails (which I used to receive fine). Do you know of a guide to setting up Drupal email functionality on godaddy? Thanks.